# Different in index vs constraint syntax

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm a bit unclear on the terminology when creating an index or constraint. For example:

- `CREATE CONSTRAINT cs ON (p:Person) ASSERT p.name IS UNIQUE`
- `CREATE INDEX my_index FOR (p:Person) ON (p.age)`

When is `FOR` used and when is `ON` used? Or are they two different versions, or is one deprecated? I've also seen `ASSERT` vs. `REQUIRE` used and also not sure when to use which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `CREATE CONTRAINT [constraint_name] ON ... ASSERT ...` appears to be old. It is not referred to specifically in the current [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/constraints/syntax/) (v4.4). However, it is referred to on the same page as deprecated for the `DROP CONSTRAINT` command.

The current syntax is consistently `CREATE CONTRAINT [constraint_name] FOR ... REQUIRE ...`

Answer (score 0):

If you use CREATE INDEX, it does not enforce unicity. So basically to speed up searches.
CREATE CONSTRAINT does enforce unicity.

When you do `:schema`, you will see that in both cases, an index is created, because also to enforce unicity, quick lookup helps al lot :)

Comment: oh I don't mean the difference between `CONSTRAINT` vs `INDEX`, I meant specifically why the `FOR` vs. `ON` is used in the syntaxes, or `ASSERT` vs `REQUIRE`. What is the difference between when those are used?